# Laravel sort data from database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello i have this function

```
 $TableB1 = \DB::table('users')
    ->join('group_user', 'users.id', '=', 'group_user.user_id')
    ->join('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'group_user.group_id')
    ->select(
       'groups.name as groupname',
       'group_user.user_id as id',
       'users.name as name',
       'users.company_id as companyID'
       )
    ->get();
```

it get data from db and display the data in view like this

what i want to do is to group the data by group.name so the team field appear in order like
  [image: Table]

> Team Ahmed
>    Team Ahmed
>   Team Hassan

but when i use groupBy('group.name') i get an error in laravel

Answer (score 7):

try orderBy().

```
 $TableB1 = \DB::table('users')
->join('group_user', 'users.id', '=', 'group_user.user_id')
->join('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'group_user.group_id')
->select(
   'groups.name as groupname',
   'group_user.user_id as id',
   'users.name as name',
   'users.company_id as companyID'
   )->orderBy('groupname')
->get();
```